# file transfer using ssh sftpg3

Tags: perl, ssh, ftp, sftp, mod-perl

I am writing a Perl script to do a secure file transfer using SSH sftpg3.exe

But I am having issue to accessing the source file.
the script able to pick the file from C:\xx\t.txt while running it from the directory

It is not showing error C:\Program is not a valid command.

```
my $sftpPath="C:\\Program Files\\client";
my $srcPath="C:\\xx\\test.txt";
my $trgCommand=$sftpPath." -D $srcPath user@host:/tmp/";
my $result=system("$trgCommand");
```

while running this script from C:\ directory it is running without error but I can not see the file in destination server.

Could you please help me sort out this file path issue ?
I want to run it from O:\ and it will pick the target file and sftpg3.exe from C:\ drive and do the file transfer (in ASCII mode) successfully.

Comment: Just to double check, if you print $trgCommand instead of running system with it, does the command output you get actually work from the cli?

Comment: no it's not working because it not able to find the sftpg3.exe and test.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the below code

```
my $cmd="sftpg3.exe " . "$src_path user@host:"; 
system("C:\\Program Files\\Client\");
system($cmd);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You might have interpolation of `@host` in your third line because you are using double quotes (`""`). Do you have `use strict` and `use warnings` turned on? There might also be an issue with the space () in the path.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $sftp_path = q{"C:\Program Files\Client\sftpg3.exe"};
my $src_path = 'C:\xx\test.txt';
my $result = system( $sftp_path, '-D', $src_path, 'user@host:/tmp/' );
say $result;
```

Let's look at what I did.

- When you <kbd>tab</kbd>-complete a path like `C:\Program Files\foo` in Windows cmd, it usually wraps them in double quotes if there is a space inside the path. So we use the [`q` operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/q.html), which is equivalent to single quotes, and put double quotes inside. That also gives us the benefit that we don't have to escape the backslash `\`. Also see [quote-like operators in perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators).
- Same goes for the source path.
- [`system`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) allows you to pass all the arguments to the program you want to run as arguments to itself and will take care of the quoting
- The double quote in `"user@host:"` will try to expand `@host` as an array. That doesn't work, because it's not defined. So there's a warning that you probably didn't see because you did not `use strict` and `use warnings`. Instead of the double quotes, use single quotes.
- I used `$sftp_path` instead of `$sftpPath` because there is a convention in Perl to use underscores and no capital letters. We like camels, but not in our variable names. :)